# Removing stuck Satco Ultra Mini GU24 CFL

Tags: bulb, stuck, cfl

[image]

I am trying to replace the Satco Ultra Mini GU24 CFLs in this fixture. I have tried the recommended twist and pull for these types, and I can twist them in place but pulling does nothing. Rough handling has already made me break a tiny piece of the left bulb and now I’m wary of the broken CFL and they’re still stuck beyond belief…any ideas?

Comment: push/twist/ pull

Answer (score 1):

A GU24 is a bipin connector like this.

[image]

and the socket looks like this

[image]

So push and twist anti-clockwise.  It will be a fraction of a turn only.

Comment: Based on this photo, I would suggest gently wiggling the bulb around if it won't come loose after turning. These kinds of mechanisms can have a lot of slop in them. And try backing off a little on the rotation -- if you rotate absolutely as far as it will go, the tabs from the bulb will hang up on the opposite end of the slots.